# ERROR: PAGENAME (ApexPage) was not found on the server

Tags: visualforce, error, mavensmate, apexpage

This message appeared when I tried to save a file, the previous things that I did was cloning the project from git and synching it to Mavensmate.

I tried to refresh from server but no luck.

Code editor I am using here is Sublime text 3.

I don't know how to solve this in order to start coding. Is there any idea about this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is coming because of your file is not save on server. Did you refresh the Project from the server?
If you didn't do that them go on Your project on sublime on Left hand and right click and refresh it from server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have found the reason, it's because I've used the wrong credentials of sandbox.